# my question is about proving a norm is a norm

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to show that $||f||=\max_{t\in [0,1]}|f(t)|$ defines a norm on $C([0,1])$.

I only have a question on the triangle inequality property. This is what I have done but I am not quite sure it is right.

Let $f,g\in C([0,1])$, then for all $t\in [0,1]$ we have

$|f(t)+g(t)|\le|f(t)|+|g(t)|\le \max_{t\in [0,1]}|f(t)|+\max_{t\in [0,1]}|g(t)|$

so  $\max_{t\in [0,1]}|f(t)|+\max_{t\in [0,1]}|g(t)|$  is an upeer bound for  $|f(t)+g(t)$|,

so $\max_{t\in [0,1]}|f(t)+g(t)|\le \max_{t\in [0,1]}|f(t)|+\max_{t\in [0,1]}|g(t)$

thus $||f+g||\le ||f||+||g||$ as desired.

Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct.